# Manipular el zoom predeterminado que tiene navegador al momento de mostrar mi pagina

Tags: html5

Como puedo manipular el zoom del navegador utilizando el estandar HTML5, es un proyecto de fundamentos del computador y no tengo mucha experiencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción, podría ser usar la propiedad CSS ***zoom*** para cambiar el tamaño de el/los elemento/s en los que estás interesado.

```js
const div = document.getElementById('prueba');

function redimensionar(tamano) {
  div.style.zoom = tamano;
}
```

```css
div#prueba {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="prueba">
  Soy feliz y ya no necesito a mis padrinos mágicos
</div>

<button onclick="redimensionar(1);">
  Tamaño normal
</button>
<button onclick="redimensionar(2);">
  Aumentar
</button>
<button onclick="redimensionar(3);">
  Aumentar más
</button>
```

Esta propiedad no es una propiedad que se encuentre estandarizada. Es por esa razón que por ejemplo *Firefox* no la soporta.
Se podría intentar usar otras alternativas similares. Como podría ser *transform: scale(ancho, alto);* dependiendo el caso.

---

Otra posibilidad, más tediosa, sería escalar las medidas de los elementos manualmente.

```js
const div = document.getElementById('prueba');

const anchoInicial = parseInt(getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('width'));
const altoInicial = parseInt(getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('height'));
const tamanoFuenteInicial = parseInt(getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

function redimensionar(tamano) {
  div.style.width = `${anchoInicial * tamano}px`;
  div.style.height = `${altoInicial * tamano}px`;
  div.style.fontSize = `${tamanoFuenteInicial * tamano}px`;
}
```

```css
div#prueba {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#prueba > p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="prueba">
  Soy feliz y ya no necesito a mis padrinos mágicos
</div>

<button onclick="redimensionar(1);">
  Tamaño normal
</button>
<button onclick="redimensionar(2);">
  Aumentar
</button>
<button onclick="redimensionar(3);">
  Aumentar más
</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responderme.